# CSS Reactive ValueBoxes in ShinyDashboard

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to customize `valueboxes` in `shinydashboard` using `css`. The issue I am finding is:

1. I cannot tag a specific `valuebox` which makes any `css` changes apply for all
2. I do not know how to make the `css` reactive based on input from the server side

Below is my code that illustrates what I am trying to do. Each value box should have a different color font for the number percentage.

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shinydashboardPlus)

rm(list=ls())

###########################/ui.R/##################################

#Header----
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  title = "Test",
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "sliders"
)

#Right SideBar----
rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

#SideBar----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  #Sidebar Menu----
  div(id = "sidebarChoices",
      #style = "position: fxed; overflow: visible;", 
      sidebarMenu(id = "menuChoice",
                  menuItem("Functional Dashboards", tabName = "MetricMenu", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                           menuSubItem("Operations", tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu", icon = icon("angle-double-right"))
                  )
      )
  )
)

#Body----
body <- dashboardBody(
  #OPS Page----
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            .small-box {background-color: #000000 !important;border-radius: 1vh !important; border-color: #D20000 !important;}
                            .small-box .icon-large {font-size: 8vh !important; bottom: -2vh !important; color: #999999 !important;}
                            .small-box h3 {font-size: 4vh !important; color: #D20000 !important;}
                            .small-box p {font-size: 1vh !important;}
                            "))),


  #OPERATIONS KPI----
  tabItem(tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu",
          #First Row: KPI Metrics----
          div(id = "Ops_FirstRow", 
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("Box1", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("Box2", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("Box3", width = 2),
                valueBoxOutput("Box4", width = 2)
              )
          )
  )
  )
#Builds Dashboard Page----
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body, rightsidebar)

###########################/server.R/###############################
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Box1 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 50

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "#FFFFFF"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "#F6FC00"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "#D20000"
    } else {Color = "FFFFFF"}

    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })

  output$Box2 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 85

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "#FFFFFF"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "#F6FC00"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "#D20000"
    } else {Color = "FFFFFF"}

    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })

  output$Box3 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 110

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "#FFFFFF"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "#F6FC00"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "#D20000"
    } else {Color = "FFFFFF"}

    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })

  output$Box4 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 98

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "#FFFFFF"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "#F6FC00"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "#D20000"
    } else {Color = "FFFFFF"}

    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })




}

#Combines Dasboard and Data together----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

The solution below works great!

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shinydashboardPlus)
library (ggplot2)
library (leaflet)
library (date)
library (tidyr)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (zoo)
library (tibble)
library (billboarder)
library (scales)
library (highcharter)
library (quantmod)
library (gplots)
library (RColorBrewer)
library (plotrix)
library (RODBC)
library (png)
library (rpivotTable)
library (lubridate)
library (timeDate)
library (shinycssloaders)
library (shinyjs)
library (DT)
library (rintrojs)
library (profvis)
library (bit64)
library (collapsibleTree)

rm(list=ls())

###########################/ui.R/##################################

#Header----
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  title = tagList(
    span(class = "logo-lg", "MRO Dash"),
    imageOutput("HLogo")),
  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
          tags$a(htmlOutput("Refresh"))
  ),
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "sliders"
)

#Right SideBar----
rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

#SideBar----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  #Sidebar Menu----
  div(id = "sidebarChoices",
      #style = "position: fxed; overflow: visible;", 
      sidebarMenu(id = "menuChoice",
                  menuItem("Functional Dashboards", tabName = "MetricMenu", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                           menuSubItem("Operations", tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu", icon = icon("angle-double-right"))
                  )
      )
  )



  #End )----
  ) #dashboard sidebar end

#Body----
body <- dashboardBody(
useShinyjs(),
  #CSS Formatting----
  #Background colors----
  #tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".sidebar {height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;}"))),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico")), 

  #   /* other links in the sidebarmenu when hovered */
  # .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{background-color: #E4551F;}
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            /*** FORMATTING BACKGROUND COLORS ***/

                            /* Top Left of Header Background */
                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color: #000000;}

                            /*Top Left of Header when Hovered */
                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #E4551F;}

                            /* Rest of the Header Background */
                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #000000;}

                            /* Main SideBar Background */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar {background-color: #1A1A1A;}

                            /* Tabs in SideBar Background */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{background-color: #1A1A1A;}

                            /* Active Tab in SideBar Background */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{background-color: #E4551F;}

                            /* Left bar on Sidebar */
                            .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li.active > a {border-left-color: #E4551F;}
                            .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li.active > a, .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li:hover > a {border-left-color: #E4551F;}

                            /* toggle button when hovered  */
                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover{background-color: #E4551F;}

                            /* Right SideBar Background */
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.control-sidebar-bg {background: #1A1A1A;}
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.nav.nav-tabs.nav-justified.control-sidebar-tabs {background: #1A1A1A;}
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.control-sidebar.control-sidebar-dark.control-sidebar-open {background: #1A1A1A;}

                            /* Body Background */ 
                            .content-wrapper, .right-side {background-color: #FFFFFF;}

                            '))),

  #Header Logo----
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            .main-header .logo {
                            padding: 0px 0px;
                            }
                            '))),
  #Boxes----
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

                            .box.box-primary{
                            border-top-color:#E4551F;
                            border-bottom-color:#E4551F;
                            border-color: #E4551F
                            border-left-color:#E4551F;
                            border-right-color:#E4551F;
                            }

                            .box.box-solid.box-primary{
                            border-color: #E4551F
                            }

                            .box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header{
                            background-color: #E4551F;
                            }


                            '))), #.nav.nav-tabs.shiny-tab-input.shiny-bound-input > li[class=active] > a {border-top-color:#E4551F;}
  #Icon----
  tags$style('.fa-plus-square-o {color:#E4551F}'),


  #OPS Page----
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            .small-box {background-color: #000000 !important;border-radius: 1vh !important; box-shadow: 0.3vh 0.3vh 0vh #CCCCCC;}
                            .small-box .icon-large {font-size: 8vh !important; bottom: -2vh !important; color: #999999 !important;}
                            .small-box h3 {font-size: 4vh !important;}
                            .small-box p {font-size: 1vh !important; color: #FFFFFF !important;}

                            .white .small-box h3{color: #FFFFFF !important;}
                            .yellow .small-box h3{color: #F6FC00 !important;}
                            .red .small-box h3{color: #D20000 !important;}

                            #DailyLinearityShip {height:25vh !important;}
                            #MonthlyLinearityShip {height:25vh !important;}
                            "))),


    #OPERATIONS KPI----
    tabItem(tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu",
            #First Row: KPI Metrics----
            div(id = "Ops_FirstRow", 
                fluidRow(
                  valueBoxOutput("Box1", width = 2),
                  valueBoxOutput("Box2", width = 2),
                  valueBoxOutput("Box3", width = 2),
                  valueBoxOutput("Box4", width = 2)
                )
            ),
            #Third Row: Linearity----
            fluidRow(
              div(id = "DailyLinearityBox",
                  box(
                    title = "Daily Shipment Linearity", status = "primary", solidHeader = FALSE,
                    highchartOutput("DailyLinearityShip") %>% withSpinner(color="#E4551F")
                  )
              ),
              div(id = "MonthlyLinearityBox",
                  box(
                    title = "Monthly Shipment Linearity", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    highchartOutput("MonthlyLinearityShip") %>% withSpinner(color="#E4551F")
                  )
              )
            ),
            #Fourth Row: WIP----   
            div(id = "Ops_FourthRow", 
                fluidRow(
                  div(id = "TimingBox",
                      tabBox(id = "Timing",
                             title = p("WIP Status",actionLink("WIPOnTimeLink", NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o"))), width = 4
                      )
                  )
                )
            )
    )
)
#Builds Dashboard Page----
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body, rightsidebar)

###########################/server.R/###############################
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Box1 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 50

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box1", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box1", Color)
    valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
  })

  output$Box2 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 85

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box2", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box2", Color)
    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })

  output$Box3 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 110

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box3", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box3", Color)
    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })

  output$Box4 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- 98

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box4", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box4", Color)
    CommercialOTDBox <- valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
    return(CommercialOTDBox)
  })


  output$MonthlyLinearityShip <- renderHighchart({

    SumIntake <- c(5,10,15,20,20,20,25,30,35,40,45,45,45)
    SumShip <- c(6,12,14,20,20,20,22,28,33,42,44,50,55)
    GoalShip <- c(7,14,21,25,25,25,30,35,40,45,55,60, 65)
    Index <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

    Linearity <- data.frame(SumIntake,SumShip,GoalShip,Index)

    highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = Linearity$Index, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.2vh"))) %>%
    hc_yAxis(gridLineWidth = 0, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.2vh"))) %>%
    hc_add_series(data  = Linearity$SumIntake, name = "Intakes",  color = "#E4551F") %>%
    hc_add_series(data  = Linearity$SumShip, name = "Shipments",  color = "#000000") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = Linearity$GoalShip, name = "Plan", type = "line",  color = "#F2A900") %>%
    hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE))) %>%
    hc_legend(enabled = TRUE, verticalAlign = "top") %>%
    hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>Day {point.x}</b><br>", allowDecimals = FALSE)

  })

  output$DailyLinearityShip <- renderHighchart({

    SumShip <- c(6,12,14,20,20,20,22,28,33,42,44,50,55)
    GoalShip <- c(7,14,21,25,25,25,30,35,40,45,55,60, 65)
    Index <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

    Linearity <- data.frame(SumShip,GoalShip,Index)

    highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = "line") %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = Linearity$Index, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.2vh"))) %>%
      hc_yAxis(gridLineWidth = 0, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.2vh"))) %>%
      hc_add_series(data  = Linearity$SumShip, name = "Shipments",  color = "#000000") %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Linearity$GoalShip, name = "Plan", type = "line",  color = "#F2A900") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE))) %>%
      hc_legend(enabled = TRUE, verticalAlign = "top") %>%
      hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>Day {point.x}</b><br>", allowDecimals = FALSE)

  })

}

#Combines Dasboard and Data together----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: CSS can be applied to an id like `#Box1`

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work, not with 'ValueBox'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `shinjys` and the `addClass` / `removeClass` functions to add a css-class. The 3 css-classes (white, yellow, red) are predefined and assigned based on the value of a `valueBox`.

Before that assignment, you have to remove all those potential classes, otherwise it will just append the css-classes and then the color wont change.

This example shows that behaviour with 2 `valueBoxes` and 2 `sliderInputs` to change the value of the valueBoxes.

**Update**: `shinyjs` requires a call to `useShinyjs()` in the UI.

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shinydashboardPlus)
library (shinyjs)

########################### CSS ##########################
css = HTML("
  .white .small-box {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  }
  .yellow .small-box {
    background-color: #F6FC00 !important;
  }
  .red .small-box {
    background-color: #D20000 !important;
  }
")

###########################/ui.R/##################################

#Header
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  title = "Test",
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "sliders"
)

#Right SideBar
rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

#SideBar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  #Sidebar Menu
  div(id = "sidebarChoices",
      #style = "position: fxed; overflow: visible;", 
      sidebarMenu(id = "menuChoice",
                  menuItem("Functional Dashboards", tabName = "MetricMenu", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                           menuSubItem("Operations", tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu", icon = icon("angle-double-right"))
                  )
      )
  )
)

#Body
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(css)),


  #OPERATIONS KPI
  tabItem(tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu",
          #First Row: KPI Metrics
          div(id = "Ops_FirstRow", 
              fluidRow(
                sliderInput("valBox1", "Change Value for Box1", min = 0, 100, 50),
                valueBoxOutput("Box1", width = 2),
                sliderInput("valBox2", "Change Value for Box2", min = 0, 100, 85),
                valueBoxOutput("Box2", width = 2)
              )
          )
  )
  )
#Builds Dashboard Page
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body, rightsidebar)

###########################/server.R/###############################
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Box1 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- input$valBox1

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box1", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box1", Color)
    valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
  })

  output$Box2 <- renderValueBox({

    Value <- input$valBox2

    lapply(c("white", "yellow", "red"), function(i) removeClass("Box2", i))

    if (Value <= 100 & Value >= 90) {Color = "white"
    } else if (Value < 90 & Value >= 80) {Color = "yellow"
    } else if (Value < 80) {Color = "red"
    } else {Color = "white"}

    addClass("Box2", Color)
    valueBox(value = paste0(Value, "%"), subtitle = "OTD DIH Commercial MTD /Goal: 90%", icon = icon("plane"), href = "#")
  })

}

#Combines Dasboard and Data together----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perfect, I tweaked it slightly to have the text of the percentage change for color only but this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. Yeah, you can add all kinds of css-style in those classes. If you liked the answer, you might consider upvoting it :)

Comment: Can you look at my edit? For some reason it's not working when I pass it into my trial CSS code. Somehow it's not taking the class.

Comment: You have to add `useShinyjs()` in the dashboardBody, otherwise shinyjs wont work and the classes wont be assigned.

Comment: Great call, overlooked that